# Get only first level child categories of current category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have Created a Taxonomy Archive template for a CTP.
In this page, before I list all the posts of the current taxonomy - I want to list all the child categories of the current taxonomy.

What I have managed to display is the whole list of child categories of this taxonomy, but I need to filter out the 2nd level children.

for example:
 
-Taxonomy
--child-taxonomy1
--child-taxonomy2
----child of child-taxonomy2

I want to display only "child-taxonomy1" and "child-taxonomy2"

Here's my code so far: http://www.codeshare.io/MQ4YT

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<ul> 
<?php
global $post;
// grab terms of current post, replace taxonomy name
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'name_of_custom_taxonomy');
// define arguments of following listing function
$args = array (
    'child_of' => $terms[0], // current post's (first) category 
    'title_li' => '', // disable display of outer list item 
    'taxonomy' => 'name_of_custom_taxonomy' // replace as well
);
// list child categories
wp_list_categories($args);
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: did you look at my code? I'm trying to get in a taxonomy archive page, not in a post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$taxonomy_name = 'product-category';
            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
            $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

            $termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy_name, array( 'parent' => $term_id, 'hide_empty' => false ) );

            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
```

Works like a charm :)